# Vertically aligning text in a link box, negating inherited CSS properties

Tags: css, inheritance

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jgallaway81/ax9wh/

```
<a href="lcars.jfx.php" class="leftbuttons buttonlinks antibutton">
  LCARS Locomotive O.S.
</a>
```

My problem is the text label in the graphic. I'm using this button design all over my site, with only the text and its size varying. When I originally designed the system (on page: http://www.fccorp.us/development/index.php and then again on http://www.fccorp.us/development/index.fccorp.php), I used the margins & padding CSS controls to get the text centered vertically within the button. But that depended on a `static` font height. Now I want to use a taller font and can't get the thing to auto center height wise. I tried

```
.leftbuttons {
  width:335px;
  height:40px;
  padding:**auto**
  20px **auto**
  45px; font-size:1em;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0px;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-weight:900;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-right:20px;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
  background-image: url(http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/1461/lcarssitebutton.png);
```

}

But all that ended up doing was chopping the image up.

I'm using the `.antibutton` to try to override a few details from the other classes in order to get what I'm trying to get. If I can solve the text `vertical-align` problem (or some nice coder here can figure out what the heck I screwed up), I also want to get the button's bottom aligned even with the text line.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add a `line-height:` to your unique cases?

for example, i added `line-height: 40px;` to `a.buttonlinks` and it centers vertically just fine.

Comment: You'd probably want to do it in em, though. The user has his font-size in em, so why screw up line-height on zoom?

Comment: yep, you're right.  principally though, line-height addresses the problem

Comment: Reason: because I never thought to add it to the CSS for the link formatting. I tried in the other classes and it never worked. Added it to the 3 link classes and adjusted the other two types of button classes and it works perfectly, thank you.